# How can I pass View parameter (TextView) from OnClickListener to public methode

Tags: java, android, view, textview

I'm trying to use the same method for different Views. Each time, I want to pass a different `TextView` to work with, as follows:

```
 ibIncreaseA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //increase the counter in textView
            increase(view);
        }
    });

ibIncreaseB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //increase the counter in textView
        increase(view);
    }
});
```

And this is the desired method:

```
public void increase (View textView ){
    int calculatedValue;
    try {
        String counter = textView.getText().toString();
        calculatedValue = Integer.parseInt(counter) + 1;
        tvNumOfTickets.setText(String.valueOf(calculatedValue));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `textView` in the method does not allow me to use `.setText()`.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try below code

```
try {
    String counter = ((TextView)textView ).getText().toString();
    calculatedValue = Integer.parseInt(counter) + 1;
    ((TextView)textView ).setText(String.valueOf(calculatedValue));
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might save you the headache of constant down casting by passing the View into the `increase()` method *as* a TextView. (i.e. - calling `increase((TextView)view);`)

Have your increase method accept a TextView instead of a View as you have it now.

```
public void increase (TextView textView ){
    ...
}
```

Comment: My view is a Class level var, sorry for not including it in the Question. I want to pass each view so the methode will work on to the passed view

Comment: @ProBul rewrote my answer, it draws on sush's answer

Answer (score -1):

```
 wallet2 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.wallet2 ) ;
//enter code here

 wallet3 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.wallet3 );
//enter code here

 walletlis(wallet2);
//enter code here

 walletlis(wallet3);
//enter code here

public void walletlis(Button wallet)
{     
  wallet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  { 
     //enter code here
   public void onClick(View view)
   { });
  }
}

//enter code here
```